# Need help with some of the Hero Academy Challenges

Tags: hero-academy

How do you do complete the following challenges:

**Council**

- Cluster Bomb

**Dark Elves**

- Let's Be Bad

**Dwarves**

- Shotgun Fun

**Tribe**

- Options Galore
- Think Carefully
- Warrior Time

Comment: Are these the single player challenges that come with the new update?

Comment: Yes they are!!,

Answer (score 11):

**Cluster Bomb**

1. Scroll the Wizard and attack the Void Monk.
2. Knock the Void Monk back with the Knight.
3. Drop the Inferno in the middle of the units.
4. Shoot the Impaler with the Archer.

**Let's Be Bad**

1. Move the Necromancer forward and knock out the Archer.
2. Spawn the Wraith on the Archer's corpse.  **DO NOT** use the Necromancer to create a Phantom out of the Archer's corpse.  The Wraith is in your deck at the bottom, and can spawn out of corpses, which is what this challenge is used to teach.  See the picture for more information.
3. Use the Wraith to take out the Ninja and Cleric.

[image: Use the Wraith!]

**Shotgun Fun**

1. Move the Gunner so that he is under the Archer.
2. Scroll the Gunner and attack the Cleric twice.  His attack will hit all three units.

**Options Galore**

1. Spawn the Warrior in front of the Wizard and attack it.
2. Spawn the Witch above the Warrior and explode the Wizard's corpse.
3. Explode the Archer's corpse.

**Think Carefully**

1. Use the Axe Thrower to attack the Archer.
2. Use the Wave on the far left to move all the units to the right.
3. Use the Warrior to knock out the Archer.
4. Use the Chieftan to attack the Wizard twice.

**Warrior Time**

1. Attack the Gunner with the Chieftan.
2. Use the Wave on the far right to move all the units to the left.
3. Attack the Gunner with the Chieftan to suck the other units in.
4. Use the Meat on the Chieftan and attack the Grenadier.

Comment: Forgot that Wraiths can spawn on corpses.  Thanks for helping me solve "Let's Be Bad"!  @Jace, please accept this correct answer.

Comment: Did they ever actually "teach" this Wraith feature? It's not mentioned at all in the unit's tooltip, or the "Game Guide" docs.

Comment: @postgoodism - I don't think so.  However, when you select a Wraith, any corpses on the battlefield are shaded like the entry points and a big yellow circle is put around them, so there are UI indicators that you can do... something.  I believe part of the reason for the challenges was to introduce players to some of the more obscure features of the game that they may not know about from the tutorial.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Did something change? I kill the archer and I click on the Wraith (and every other unit) and the space doesn't glow like @JasonBerkan says and I tried dropping them on the unconscious archer and it won't let me.

Comment: As per the [discussion here](http://www.robotentertainment.com/forum/topic/Update-11-14-2012), Wraith spawning is broken in the latest update.  Not sure when it will be fixed, which means the Let's Be Bad challenge cannot currently be completed.