# How do you complete the Three vs Three challenge?

Tags: hero-academy

I would really appreciate a guide for the Three vs Three challenge in the Dark Elves section.

Comment: I've removed Cluster Bomb from your question, as it is [answered here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75070/need-help-with-some-of-the-hero-academy-challenges).

Answer (score 1):

I used the Necromancer's special ability:

1. **Buff the Necromancer** (use the scroll)
2. Necromancer => **kill the Cleric**
3. Necromancer => **make a Phantom with the Cleric's body**
4. Phantom => **kill an archer**
5. Phantom => **kill other archer**

[image: Buffed Necromancer]
[image: Phantom]

Answer (score 0):

**Three vs Three** is all about the Necromancer.  The other units are red herrings, since they don't have the range to deal with three enemy units in five action points.

1. Move your Necromancer ahead one space.
2. Scroll your Necromancer.
3. Attack the Cleric with your Necromancer, knocking her out.
4. Attack one of the Archers with your Necromancer, knocking her out.
5. Attack the final Archer with your Necromancer, knocking her out.